# Server-side application, UI application and ...?

Tags: computer-science

I know that there are server-side application and UI-application. But how to call application which we fire in console? It is not server side and now UI app.

Comment: In simplest terms a “program”, a tool, a utility …?

Answer (score 0):

I think they are commonly known as **console application**. From Wikipedia:

"*A console application is a computer program designed to be used via a text-only computer interface, such as a text terminal, the command line interface of some operating systems (Unix, DOS, etc.) or the text-based interface included with most Graphical User Interface (GUI) operating systems, such as the Win32 console in Microsoft Windows, the Terminal in Mac OS X, and xterm in Unix. A user typically interacts with a console application using only a keyboard and display screen, as opposed to GUI applications, which normally require the use of a mouse or other pointing device. Many console applications such as command line interpreters are command line tools, but numerous text-based user interface (TUI) programs also exist.*"

It's called via text-only, so it's not a server-side application nor a UI one.

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Comment: But console application can be a server. So it's a server-side app.

Comment: You didn't say that in your question, where you wrote: "But how to call application which we fire in console? It is not server side and now UI app." In your words, this applications are not server side nor UI app. That's why I think they are commonly known as console applications.